# Consequences of a US attack on North Korea?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, nuclear-weapons, north-korea

This week, the US is carrying out joint military exercises with South Korea in which they practice the steps they would go through in order to carry out 'rehearsals of surgical strikes on North Korea’s main nuclear and missile facilities and "decapitation raids" by special forces targeting the North’s leadership.' ([source](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/in-drills-us-south-korea-practice-striking-norths-nuclear-plants/2016/03/06/46e6019d-5f04-4277-9b41-e02fc1c2e801_story.html?hpid=hp_hp-more-top-stories_uskorea-1145pm%3Ahomepage%2Fstory))

I assume the rationale for this scenario is that they assume they could eliminate all of North Korea's nuclear weapons (which may not even be appropriately set up for immediate use?) before they could be used against North Korea or Japan. So assuming the result is only conventional warfare, what would be the likely consequences for South Korea? Would a great deal of the South Korean civilian population close to the border be killed? Could North Korea strike back with conventional weapons against Seoul too quickly for anyone to prevent it?

Politically, would the point of these exercises be to deter a North Korean first strike? To signal that there is limited time for sanctions to produce the desired effect? To try to maneuver the Chinese closer to a position acceptable for US and South Korean security?

Comment: Such hypothetical scenarios make bad questions for the stackexchange concept, because there are just too many variables which influence the outcome.

Comment: All the above..